# Passing an array of Strings C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

i have the following code in a function

```
char MenuOptions[7][200];
strcpy(MenuOptions[0], "Create New / Modify Existing Customer");
strcpy(MenuOptions[1], "Create New / Modify Existing Product");
strcpy(MenuOptions[2], "List All customers");
strcpy(MenuOptions[3], "List All Products");
strcpy(MenuOptions[4], "Batch Update of New Stock");
strcpy(MenuOptions[5], "Create Customer Order");
strcpy(MenuOptions[6], "View Last Order for Customer");
switch (displayMenu("Main Menu", MenuOptions, 7, TRUE)) {
etc....
```

and

```
char displayMenu(char *name, char *options[], int menuLength,
    enBoolean QuitEnabled) {

    int i;
    printf("%s: \n", name);
    for (i = 0; i < menuLength; i++) {
        printf("\t %d %s.\n", (i + 1), options[i]);
    }
    if (QuitEnabled == TRUE)
        printf("\t Q. Quit\n");
etc
```

once the displayMenu method is entered though, the MenuOptions array seems to be lost from memory. I tried seeing what options[i] is through the expression window in eclipse and it says that it's "out of bounds" as a value

Comment: Posting `etc` as your code doesn't really help anything. Why not just post the actual code instead?

Comment: @netcoder, the use of `ect` seems completely appropriate, if not preferable. The error he is reporting seems to be happening before those lines would ever be reached. Posting to much code just makes it harder to read.

Comment: `char* MenuOptions[] = {"Create New / Modify Existing Customer", ... , "View Last Order for Customer"};` but you need to post the return section of displayMenu ... it should be an integer value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, turn on warning options in your compiler. Your compiler should have warned you there was a type mismatch.

`MenuOptions` is an array of seven arrays of 200 `char`. When `displayMenu` is called, and `MenuOptions` is passed as a parameter, `MenuOptions` is automatically converted from an array to a pointer to the first of the seven arrays of 200 char.

In `displayMenu`, the `options` parameter is declared with `char *options[]`. This means that `options` is an array of pointers to `char`. In function parameters, `[]` is special; it suggests that an array will be passed for this parameter, but the array is actually passed by the address of its first argument. Thus, this declaration says that `options` is a pointer to the first of some number of pointers to `char`.

So, you are passing a pointer to the first of seven arrays of 200 char, but the function expects to receive a pointer to the first of some number of pointers to `char`.

One way to fix this is to change the declaration of `options` to `char (*options)[200]`. This says that `options` is a pointer to (the first of) arrays of 200 char.

A better way to fix it may be to change MenuOptions:

```
static const char *MenuOptions[] =
{
    "Create New / Modify Existing Customer",
    "Create New / Modify Existing Product",
    "List All customers",
    "List All Products",
    "Batch Update of New Stock",
    "Create Customer Order",
    "View Last Order for Customer",
};
```

(You do not need “7” in the brackets because the compiler will count the strings for you.)

Then you do not need to change the declaration of `options`, except that I have added `const`:

```
char displayMenu(char *name, const char *options[], int menuLength,
    enBoolean QuitEnabled) {…
```

Now:

- `MenuOptions` is an array of seven pointers to strings (arrays of char). It is passed as a pointer to pointers to strings, and `options` is a pointer to pointers to strings, so the types match.
- `MenuOptions` does not take more space than required. Before, it was defined with 200 characters for each string. Now, each string takes only as much space as it needs (plus a null character at the end and a pointer to the string in the `MenuOptions` array).
- `const` is added to avoid accidentally changing the strings.
- `MenuOptions` is declared `static`, so that it is initialized at compile time, and you do not need to copy strings into it at run time.

Finally, you can replace the “7” in the call to `displayMenu` with `sizeof MenuOptions / sizeof *MenuOptions`. This divides the size of the array by the size of an element of the array, giving the number of elements in the array. This is preferred over hard-coding a constant because it eliminates the possibility that somebody might change the size of the array without changing the hard-coded constant.

Comment: when it comes to the printf however it's still failing. using the (*options*)[200] should i call options[i] in the printf. And just to verify. passing MenuOptions is right (not &MenuOptions) right?

Comment: @mangusbrother: The code works for me in both the ways I have described above. You may have another error. In order for people to help, you **must** show code that is complete enough for other people to copy and execute.

Comment: @mangusbrother: Yes, you would pass just `MenuOptions`, not `&MenuOptions`.

Comment: it's still not printing the values. Minimized the code:
displayMenu(char *name, const char *options[], int menuLength) {
 int i;
 printf("%s: \n", name);
 for (i = 0; i < menuLength; i++) {
  printf("\t %d %s.\n", (i + 1), options[i]);
 }
}
int main(){
static const char *MenuOptions[] =
 {
     "Create New / Modify Existing Customer",
     "Create New / Modify Existing Product",
     "List All customers",
     "List All Products",
     "Batch Update of New Stock",
     "Create Customer Order",
     "View Last Order for Customer",
 };
displayMenu("Main Menu", MenuOptions,7);
}

Comment: @mangusbrother: When I compile and execute that, it prints the seven strings. Things to check: (0) Did you compile and execute the new code, not old code? (1) If you include `printf("Hello, world.\n");` as the first line in `main`, does “Hello, world.” appear when you run the program? (2) Does anything appear when you run the program? Is there an error message, garbage output, or anything at all? Is there a window displayed where output would appear?

Comment: ok.. tried running the executable directly from CMD. it worked. I guess eclipse has some trouble with printfs...
THanks

Answer (score 1):

The type of `options` in `displayMenu` needs to be `char (*options)[200]`. not `char *options[]`.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`. `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize an array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`".  In this case, `MenuOptions` is a 7-element array of 200-element arrays of `char`; by the rule above, it will decay to an expression of type "pointer to 200-element array of `char`".

As written, the type of `options` is `char **`; `options[i]` gives you the `i`'th pointer to `char` after the base of the array, not the `i`'th *200-element array of `char`*.

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
char displayMenu(char *name, char options[][200], int menuLength, enBoolean QuitEnabled)
```

Comment: Considering that only passes one string, it would break the OP's `displayMenu` function which is printing strings `%s` in a loop

Answer (score 0):

Change your input type:

```
char displayMenu(char *name, char *options[], ...
```

to reflect that it's a multidimensional array:

```
char displayMenu(char *name, char options[][200], ...
```

Other options that will work:

```
char displayMenu(char *name, char options[7][200], ...

char displayMenu(char *name, char (*options)[200], ...
```

The main point is when passing multidimensional arrays all dimensions past the first, need to be passed as well.